# YouTube Player API Event Callbacks on Quatiles and mitPoints

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I'm working on an youtube attention measurement and thus want to track the events of firsQuartile, mitPoint and thirdQuartile of playback of an youtube video.

I was just wondering whether it is anyhow possible to trigger event callbacks on firstQuartile, mitPoint and thirdQuartile through the youtube api?

From what I can see the [Youtube API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=de) only support callbacks for player state change on pause,loading,end, ... but not for playback times.

Is the only way to achiev it to poll the playback time or is there any proper event based solution?